# Open a text file with a dot in the file path

Tags: vim, sed, clearcase

Is this even possible?  I am trying to script this install of IBM Clearcase and the path to it is like:

```
 ../disk1/InstallerImage_linux_gtk.x86/install.xml
```

The script barfs at the .x86 and it says "No such file or directory."

So I tried to just do vim ../disk1/InstallerImage_linux_gtk.x86/install.xml in a terminal and it opens the .x86 like a folder and allows you to select a file to edit instead of opening it directly.

Is there a way around this? Would the only way be to rename the folder before, do the sed voodoo and then move it back with the . in the name?

I guess I missed the obvious.  I guess I could cd to the directory first and then do sed -i '' install.xml.

More info:
RHEL 6.5
Bash Script

Comment: Neither `vim` nor `sed` care whether or not you have a `.` in your directory or file name so whatever problem you are experience it is not related to either of those tools. Please provide more context - are you running a UNIX shell or a Windows cmd prompt or something else? What OS/hardware/terminal type/etc.? You say `I am trying to script this...` - script it in what tool/language? Edit your question to show a small script that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to script a silent ClearCase installation, using one of the [sample response files for Rational ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21351501).
That would avoid the need to open any file in vim.

See "[Installing silently](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_installing_silently_overview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F2-1-0-1-1&lang=en)", which involves the following steps:

1. Run a silent install of Installation Manager using the Installation Manager installer.
2. Obtain a copy of the product response file and update it for your environment. If you want to record a response file using Installation Manager, see the Installation Manager information center for instructions.
3. Run a silent install of the Rational product using the Installation Manager.

Comment: ok can we ignore the clearcase thing then and just answer the question assuming it asking about a script?  I'm curious what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created a file with a seriously strange file name.  Do this:

```
$ cd /path/to/where/you/run/the/script/from
$ file ..
$ file ../disk1
$ file ../disk1/InstallerImage_linux_gtk.x86
$ file ../disk1/InstallerImage_linux_gtk.x86/install.xml
```

Every component of the relative path (beginning with "..") must be a directory.  Only the final line should claim to be an ordinary file.

Comment: I didn't create the file, IBM did.  All I did was extract them.